# How do I install a Windows program in an ISO into Wine?

Tags: wine, iso

I have a file named X.iso.  In this file there is a Windows application named X that I want to install then use. How can I install a Windows application file named X that is embedded in an ISO file into Wine and then be able to use it?

Note :

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. 
I have wine .

Comment: You may try AcetoneISO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mount an ISO image in Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278912/mount-an-iso-image-in-wine)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create a directory where you will mount the disk, say inside `/media/`

`sudo mkdir /media/x`

now mount the iso using mount command like

`sudo mount -o loop <PATH_ISO>  /media/x`

for unmount use `umount`

Answer (score 6):

Install acetoneiso by `sudo apt-get install acetoneiso` command.

The open it by typing `acetoneiso` in the dash, and click on the icon.

[image]

The click on the "Mount" button. And select the iso file to mount.

[image]

The open Nautilus *(File browser)* to see the iso mounted on a folder named `1`.

[image]

Then you should be able to install program from the iso file.

> See this [community documentation about installing software using wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine)

Answer (score 2):

You can just double-click the ISO in the file-manager to open it. You can also right-click on it, and choose `Archive Mounter`, which should be the default, to open it with.

Comment: In this case, Can he install it from there? The question is because, I sometimes failed to execute from the iso.

Comment: Yes. Assuming wine is installed correctly, double-clicking on an .exe in there should work as expected. If not, the mount should also be accessible in the terminal via the ~/.gvfs/ directory at this point. And it doesn't require making temporary directories, installing extra software you'll use only once, or root access with sudo.

Comment: @dobey have you tested this? In my testing I am unable to execute programs in Wine that are mounted with the Archive Mounter.

Comment: @Caltor I can't test it reliably on 64-bit. Perhaps there are some bugs in wine or other parts, which need to be fixed. I found a MultiArch bug just trying this now, even.

Comment: @dobey I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit and I had to mount it from the command line for wine to see it.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount that iso, and then just use the files the way you want. For example:

```
sudo mount X.iso /media/isoimage/ -o loop
```

where directory isoimage exists in /media

To unmount:

```
sudo umount /media/isoimage
```

Nautilus should be able to mount isos

Answer (score 1):

Try open nautilus, right-click the file and select "Disk Image Mounter". It got mounted for me. Although I couldn't mount it using other CMD ways.

Answer (score 0):

Mount the ISO with:

```
sudo mount -o loop ~/Path to/X.iso /mnt
```

You may then browse to `/mnt` and execute your `exe` using Wine.